# App engine not working in US west coast but works in US central?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have set my app engine region to us-central. I can access it from there, but I cannot access it from the west coast

It displays a "website coming soon" page, and not my website. Does app engine not working worldwide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've deployed an app to any App Engine region, it will be accessible (with notable exceptions) globally.

"website coming soon" is not an error response that App Engine provides.

I suspect you're using the incorrect URL to access your App Engine app. You should be able to determine the correct URL from the App Engine Console.

Comment: You are correct. I sent my friend the full url link and it worked somehow. Idiot probably messed up and made me have an headache!